# Uppercase for first letter with php

Tags: php, string, codeigniter

How can I convert to uppercase for the following example :

```
title-title-title
```

Result should be:

```
Title-Title-Title
```

I tried with ucwords but it converts like this: Title-title-title

---

I currently have this:

```
echo $title = ($this->session->userdata('head_title') != '' ? $this->session->userdata('head_title'):'Our Home Page');
```

Comment: you could explode the strings first, then capitalize each exploded string

Comment: ^and implode afterwords

Comment: Hyphens are no word delimiters - you'd have to separate them yourself. Also if your input is not only ASCII then use `$sOutput= mb_convert_case( $sInput, MB_CASE_TITLE, 'UTF-8' );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular string example, you could explode the strings first, use that function `ucfirst()` and apply to all exploded strings, then put them back together again:

```
$string = 'title-title-title';
$strings = implode('-', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $string)));
echo $strings;
```

Should be fairly straightforward on applying this:

```
$title = '';
if($this->session->userdata('head_title') != '') {
    $raw_title = $this->session->userdata('head_title'); // title-title-title
    $title = implode('-', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $raw_title)));
} else {
    $title = 'Our Home Page';
}

echo $title;
```

Comment: @NavinRauniyar and this `title-title-title` is inside `$this->session->userdata('head_title')`?

Comment: If none of the answers are working, like you said in your update, you are using all of the answers incorrectly :)

Comment: Should I use just only to 'head-title' ?

Comment: Yeah, I may be using wrong way, how should I do for that?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar you just need to substitute variable names, quite straightforward, since most operations is just mainly inside that one line.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar oh okay, that might be too much for a one liner, like this? `echo $title = ($this->session->userdata('head_title') != '') ? implode('-', array_map('ucfirst', explode('-', $this->session->userdata('head_title')))) : 'Our Home Page';` ugggh.. its too much. anyways, im glad this helped

Comment: But one liner is working fine for me, it's amazed me :)

Answer (score 4):

```
echo str_replace(" ","-",ucwords(str_replace("-"," ","title-title-title")));
```

**[Fiddle](https://eval.in/229281)**

**Output:**

```
Title-Title-Title
```

Comment: @RichardBernards Very Well :)

Answer (score 1):

#### [Demo](http://ideone.com/LRKbZg)

Not as swift as Ghost's but a touch more readable for beginners to see what's happening.

```
//break words on delimiter
$arr = explode("-", $string);

//capitalize first word only
$ord = array_map('ucfirst', $arr);

//rebuild the string
echo implode("-", $ord);
```

The `array_map()` applies callback to the elements of the given array. Internally, it traverses through the elements in our word-filled array `$arr` and applies the function `ucfirst()` to each of them. Saves you couple of lines.

Answer (score -1):

Edit #2

This isn't working for the new information added to op, as there is an answer this won't be updated to reflect that.

Edit #1

```
$var = "title-title-title";
$var = str_replace (" ", "_", ucwords (str_replace (" ", "_", $var));
```

Old, non-working

```
$var = "title-title-title";
$var = implode("-", ucwords (explode("-", $var)));
```

Comment: `ucwords()` expects a string, not an array!

Comment: Oh right, replace implode and explode with str_repalce (); (This is why you test before posting.)

Answer (score -2):

try the following:

```
$str='title-title-title';
$s='';
foreach(explode('-',$str) as $si){
    $s.= ($s ? "-":"").ucfirst($si);
}
```

`$s` should be `Title-Title-Title` at this point

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Sorry about that. Forgot to add the `ucfrist()`. Editted.